# AWS S3 integration in Swift 2.2 Xcode 7.3 gives error

Tags: ios, swift, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I have integrated the AWS S3 ADK version 2.4.9 in iOS App. I'm seeing the below weird issue in my xcode.

> Couldn't read credentials provider configurations from `Info.plist`. Please check your `Info.plist` if you are providing the SDK configuration values through `Info.plist`.

How can I resolve this?

Comment: The error seems pretty clear. Have you checked your Info.plist? If so, and you still can't figure it out, you'll need to include it with your question otherwise we won't be able to help.

Comment: While integrating with AWS s3 sdk they did not mention anything of this sort though !  Not sure what to include in info.plist  .. any idea ?  Referring to http://docs.aws.amazon.com/mobile/sdkforios/developerguide/setup.html for integration and also am using cocoapods for integration ...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to set the default SDK configuration through code or info.plist file of your app to use the `defaultS3` client.

**To do it via info.plist:**

You need to replace the pool id and the regions for cognito identity id and S3 below.

```
<key>AWS</key>
    <dict>
        <key>CredentialsProvider</key>
        <dict>
            <key>CognitoIdentity</key>
            <dict>
                <key>Default</key>
                <dict>
                    <key>PoolId</key>
                    <string>YOUR_POOL_ID_HERE</string>
                    <key>Region</key>
                    <string>USEast1</string>
                </dict>
            </dict>
        </dict>
        <key>S3</key>
        <dict>
            <key>Default</key>
            <dict>
                <key>Region</key>
                <string>USEast1</string>
            </dict>
        </dict>
    </dict>
```

**To do it via code**

```
AWSCognitoCredentialsProvider *credentialsProvider = [[AWSCognitoCredentialsProvider alloc] initWithRegionType:CognitoRegionType
                                                                                                identityPoolId:CognitoIdentityPoolId];
AWSServiceConfiguration *configuration = [[AWSServiceConfiguration alloc] initWithRegion:DefaultServiceRegionType
                                                                     credentialsProvider:credentialsProvider];
AWSServiceManager.defaultServiceManager.defaultServiceConfiguration = configuration;
```

Thanks,
Rohan

Comment: Big help. Mostly every single tutorial or example uses S3TransferManager instead of S3 in their info.plist.